# SioChatDemo Socket.io Example in C++

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, socket.io

I'm trying to get the SioChatDemo working here (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp). However, I'm getting this error:

```
  sio_socket.cpp
  1>c:\projects\socket.io-client-cpp\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\common\functional.hpp(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/bind.hpp': No such file or directory
  1>  sio_client.cpp
  1>c:\projects\socket.io-client-cpp\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\common\functional.hpp(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/bind.hpp': No such file or directory
  1>  sio_client_impl.cpp
  1>c:\projects\socket.io-client-cpp\lib\websocketpp\websocketpp\common\functional.hpp(55): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/bind.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I've built boost so I have both a C:\boost_1_58_0 (downloaded) and a C:\boost (contains include and lib).

I added C:\boost\include to "Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Additional Include Directories" and C:\boost\lib to ".. > Linker > Additional Library Directories"

I checked and there's a bind.hpp here: C:\boost\include\boost-1_58\boost\bind

Why won't it load?

Comment: You need to append "boost-1_58" as well. So the include directory should be "C:\boost\include\boost-1_58".

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm running into the problem I had before:

"error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ)"

Other SO posts seem to indicate it's b/c boost was built in the wrong architecture (64bit vs 32bit) but I've tried both and that hasn't fixed it.